# What is the difference between Local/Remote/Dynamic SSH tunneling?

Tags: ssh-tunnel

In Putty, there are three tunneling options:

[image]

Can someone explain what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [puTTY documentation](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/docs.html), specifically, [4.23 The Tunnels Panel](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-portfwd) section:

> Set one of the ‘Local’ or ‘Remote’ radio buttons, depending on whether you want to forward a local port to a remote destination (‘Local’) or forward a remote port to a local destination (‘Remote’). Alternatively, select ‘Dynamic’ if you want PuTTY to provide a local SOCKS 4/4A/5 proxy on a local port (note that this proxy only supports TCP connections; the SSH protocol does not support forwarding UDP).

- Local -- Forward local port to remote host.
- Remote -- Forward remote port to local host.
- Dynamic -- Act as a [SOCKS proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS). This requires special support from the software that connects to it, however the destination address is obtained dynamically at runtime rather than being fixed in advance.

Comment: What is the benefit of using SOCKS5?

Comment: @LanceBaynes: Benefits? As when compared to what?  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: sry, against the Local/Remote

Comment: @lanceBaynes: The configuration of the resources you are accessing will determine which of the three options you need to use.  This isn't a case of one option being "better" than the others.

Comment: I'd definitely give this an upvote if this answer gave me a better clue of what Dynamic means. "SOCKS 4/4A/5 proxy" doesn't mean anything to me. Although I'm sure I could Google it. Does "Dynamic" perhaps forward in both directions??

Answer (score 33):

The answer from jscott is correct, however after reading it, it was still not completely clear to me when should I use local and when remote. So I researched further, and I have found the answer [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding):

Use **local** if you have a service running on a machine that can be reached from the remote machine, and you want to access it directly from the local machine. After setting up the tunneling you will be able to access the service using your local host IP (127.0.0.1)

Use **remote** if you have a service that can be reached from the local machine, and you need to make it available to the remote machine. It opens the listening socket on the machine you have used SSH to log into.

**Dynamic** is like local, but on the client side it behaves like a SOCKS proxy. Use it if you need to connect with a software that expects SOCKS forwarding.

Comment: Specifically, remote opens the listening socket on the machine you have used SSH to log into.

Comment: @FalconMomot Exactly. I have added your remark to the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: A decade later and this is still the clearest description of how this works that I can find anywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

### I have drawn some sketches

The machine, where the ssh tunnel command is typed (or in your case: Putty with tunneling is started) is called **»your host«**.

[image: ssh tunnel starting from local]

---

[image: ssh tunnel starting from remote]

### static (options `-L` *local* and `-R` *remote*)

1. local: `-L Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.`

`ssh -L sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **local** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from the `connectToHost` machine.

2. remote: `-R Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.`

`ssh -R sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **remote** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from your local machine.

#### dynamic (option `-D`)

`-D` is like `-L` (local) but instead of fowarding to one and only one specific remotehost and port, SSH acts as a **SOCKS proxy** to the remotehost. Your program using the tunnel needs to support socks proxies. Or you need to help it with some tricks (**see examples below**).

**What does a Socks proxy do?** It accepts all your requests and forwards it dynamically to the remote hosts and ports, that the original program wanted it to (**see examples below**).

### Usage examples of `-D` (dynamic / socks)

If you want to tunnel your browser traffic (with Firefox for example), you do **not only want to access ONE website (remotehost and port), but surf freely in the www. So you need a dynamic tunnel**, a socks proxy.

On your computer (your host) you do:

```
ssh -D 5000 remotehost   # or the equivalent option "dynamic" with putty
```

#### Firefox traffic tunnelled

For this you can edit your Firefox configuration, so that your browser uses your socks proxy. Type in the Firefox address bar:

```
about:config
```

Now edit the following values:

```
network.proxy.socks             string localhost
network.proxy.socks_port        integer 5000
network.proxy.socks_remote_dns  boolean true
network.proxy.type              integer 1   (0 ist default)
media.peerconnection.enabled    boolean false (true ist default)
```

You can now surf in the internet without anybody at the strange place knowing what you do.

#### more general: use `tsocks` application with a file `/etc/tsocks.conf`

Contents of the config file:

```
local = 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0   # no proxy for local network
server = localhost    # proxy-server (your host)
server_type = 5       # socks5
server_port = 5000
```

You can now start program with tsocks in front of it, so that it uses the socks proxy.

```
tsocks thunderbird
tsocks mplayer -playlist http://bassdrive.com/bassdrive.m3u
```

#### curl

Easy to use with curl:

```
ALL_PROXY="socks5h://localhost:5000" curl http://blabbla.abc
```

or just

```
curl --proxy socks5h://localhost:5000 http://blabbla.abc
```

#### combine `ALL_PROXY` and `tsocks`

`wget` needs `tsocks`, because `wget` doesn’t support proxies. If you do both, you are safe (mostly):
The `script` will use `tsocks` or `ALL_PROXY` variable:

```
ALL_PROXY="socks5h://localhost:5000" tsocks script
```

#### for youtube-dl

```
youtube-dl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:5000 http://blaaaa.bla
```

### To set it up with Putty (*local* forward example)

Start Putty and enter your usual connection settings (Hostname or IP address)
In the tree on the left side, navigate to

Connection
→ SSH
→ Tunnels

and create a new *local* tunnel with the source port `123` and the destination `localhost:456`.

Do not forget to click on *Add*.

Then navigate back to *session* and click *Save* to keep your settings for the next time. Now you can use the saved connection to log in to your server and after you successfully log in, every time you connect to port `123` on your host you will actually connect to port `456` on the server.

[image: create forward tunnel with putty]

Comment: I generally hate new answers to old established posts but this is absolutely excellent.

Answer (score 3):

Local / Remote chooses whether you're connecting to a local port or a remote port (your own pc or another pc)

Dynamic is for a SOCKS proxy

See 4.19.2 Port forwarding http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.54/htmldoc/Chapter4.html

Answer (score -3):

a local server is, well, local

typically it means a local server is connected on your LAN (local area network) and a remote server is not on you lan but connected over your WAN (wide area network)
remote could be next door or the next continent or it could be in the same room, simply on separate network.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Unfortunately your answer does not contribute or add to the discussion, especially for a question which was answered last year.  Check out any open questions and see if you can help there instead.

Comment: This isn't really relevant in context.  You wouldn't set this according to the location of the server on the network, but rather whether you want to access the tunnel from the local machine (on which putty is running) or the remote machine (on which sshd is running).